# How to build a regex pattern to verify a spanish car enrollment

Tags: java, regex

I'm new in java and I need to validate this two patters to can verify a spanish car enrollment.

This is the two possibilities that I can have:
Pattern 1:LL NNNN LL 
Pattern 2:L NNNN LLL

L = letter
N = number

The implementation could be something like this, once I get the pattern to can do it?:

```
String validPatter = " ";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(validPatter );

        String text ="M 0123 AA";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

        if(matcher.matches()){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
```

Comment: This is the first link from googling "How to write a regular expression": http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{2}\s\d{4}\s[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]\s\d{4}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}` you might be able to get a better one than this, but using the program Expresso to test it, it works. You need to research Regex, as there should be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to check spanish enrollment, you can use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$|^\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{3}$

static final private Pattern patternEnrollment = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$|^\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{3}$");

    public static boolean validateEnrollment(String enrollmentToValidate) {
        return patternEnrollment.matcher(enrollmentToValidate).matches();
    }
```

This pattern is for:

Old enrollment:
L NNNN L
L NNNN LL
LL NNNN LL
LL NNNN L

New Enrollment:
NNNN L

Answer (score 1):

Here is Regex you could use to find both patterns:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\s\d{4}\s[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]\s\d{4}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}
```

Explanation of above regex:

`[a-zA-Z]{2}\s\d{4}\s[a-zA-Z]{2}` this will find pattern 1

`[a-zA-Z]\s\d{4}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}` this will find pattern 2

`|` is an OR condition.

I have tested this on a Regex program called Expresso, which i suggest you take a look at.

There are plenty of resources online on how to use Regex and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two regex for this e.g.

`^[a-zA-Z]{2} \d{4} [a-zA-Z]{2}$` for `LL NNNN LL`
`^[a-zA-Z]{1} \d{4} [a-zA-Z]{3}$` for `L NNNN LLL`

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{2} \d{4} [a-zA-Z]{2}$");
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{1} \d{4} [a-zA-Z]{3}$");
Matcher m = pattern1.matcher("MM 0123 AA");
Matcher m2 = pattern2.matcher("M 0123 AAA");
```

See here for the demo https://regex101.com/r/zA9TNK/2